# extern inline vs #define macro

Tags: c, c99

I recently encountered a codebase that favors the use of macros over extern inline functions. The language used here is C99, and the specific implementation is particularly performance sensitive (and so the argument given for the use of macro's is to avoid function calls / stack frame setup for frequently invoked functions).

As an improvement to readability, I've suggested that macro's be removed in favor of extern inline functions. For example, instead of:

```
#define FooBar(_AnArg, _AnotherArg)                      \
{                                                        \
    if (_AnotherArg)                                     \
    {                                                    \
        ...                                              \
    }                                                    \
    else                                                 \
    {                                                    \
        ...                                              \
    }                                                    \
}
```

I'm suggesting:

```
extern inline void FooBar(void* anArg, bool anotherArg) {
   ...
}
```

Looking over the generated assembly my function appears to be properly inlined and is therefore just as efficient as the macro while being easier to read and debug.

Is there any consideration of function inlining I am overlooking? Are there other benefits to macro use that I am not considering?

Comment: It depends on what they do.

Comment: Also, dont use `extern inline`. Define it `inline` and `extern` it normally

Comment: inline functions can access static variables in the file they are defined in, and called in other files. Macros can't

Comment: I just say use inline functions if you need to access static variables from another file

Comment: My 2 cents, the only case I've seen where macros should be used instead of functions is for logging that records line numbers (you need the text substitution in that case to get the right line number). Otherwise I avoid them like the plague. They're harder to read and understand (IMO), harder to debug, and more prone to errors/being used incorrectly. I have a colleague who macros everything he can, nests them together. It drives me nuts, but I'm sure there's a pro-macro camp who would love his code.

Comment: @Asadefa: How do you figure macros cannot access static objects defined in other files? For an object defined in another translation unit to be accessible by identifier, the identifier must have external linkage. If a declaration of that identifier with external linkage is in the present translation unit, then the identifier can be used either by an inline function in which the declaration is visible or by a macro for which the declaration is visible where the macro is used.

Comment: @Asadefa: What does “`extern` it normally” mean? Why make an inline function `extern` at all instead of `static`?

Answer (score 1):

`extern inline` functions will cause to emit external symbols. Macros are only visible from the point they were defined. If you put `extern inline` function in a header file and two `.c` source files include that header, then your linker should complain with a "multiple definitions of the same function" error.

Use `static inline` for replacing macros.